# Placemark not giving city name in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, cllocation, clgeocoder

I am using this code in which I am getting Placemark but it not giving the city name.
Earlier I am using MKReverse Geocoder to get the placemark in which I am getting the city name but as in iOS 6 it showing deprecated because the Apple developer added everything in CLLocation.

So I used this code:

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    NSLog(@"location is %@",location);

    CLGeocoder *fgeo = [[[CLGeocoder alloc] init] autorelease];

    // Reverse Geocode a CLLocation to a CLPlacemark
    [fgeo reverseGeocodeLocation:location
          completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){

               // Make sure the geocoder did not produce an error
               // before continuing
               if(!error){
                    // Iterate through all of the placemarks returned
                    // and output them to the console
                    for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks){
                           NSLog(@"%@",[placemark description]);
                           city1= [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*) kABPersonAddressCityKey];
                           NSLog(@"city is %@",city1);
                    }
               }
               else{
                    // Our geocoder had an error, output a message
                    // to the console
                    NSLog(@"There was a reverse geocoding error\n%@",
                                         [error localizedDescription]);
               }
         }
    ];
```

}

Here as I am seeing in console in  `NSLog(@"%@",[placemark description]);`
it's giving output like :- abc road name,abc road name, state name,country name.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to NSLog the address you have to compose it doing something like this:

```
NSString *street = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
NSString *city = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey];
NSString *state = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey];
NSString *country = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressCountryKey];
NSString *zip = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey];

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Address Is: %@, %@ %@, %@, %@", street, zip, city, state, country];

NSLog(@"%@", message);
```

Or you can iterate through the array returned by:

```
NSArray *array = [[placemark addressDictionary] objectForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"];
```

If you want to simply print the dictionary content, do:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[placemark addressDictionary] description]);
```

Comment: Sorry, this answer is not so clear because I was thinking that your problem was trying to nslog all the dictionary, only now I read the real question in the post title... Do you see the city using FormattedAddressLines? Your code seems fine, have you tried with another location?

Answer (score 4):

Three things that I can see could use some attention...

First, this method is deprecated ([see documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)):

```
(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Try using this instead:

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Your most current location is the last item in the array `locations` so:

```
 /* 
 According to the Apple docs, the array of locations keeps the most recent location as the
 last object in the array 
 */
CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@", location);
```

Second, if you're using ARC, the autorelease message is unnecessary: `CLGeocoder *fgeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];` works fine.

Lastly, according to the Apple documentation for CLPlacemark has a property `locality` which should return the city for the placemark. So

```
for(CLPlacemark *placemark in placemarks){
    NSLog(@"%@",[placemark description]);
    NSString *city1 = [placemark locality];
    NSLog(@"city is %@",city1); }
```

If you just want the city, the `addressDictionary` property seems to be overkill. According to the [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html) addressDictionary is formatted to return stuff in an ABPerson object, which I'd assume you'd have to parse to get the city. Placemark locality seems much simpler...

I tested my suggestions in a Geocoding app that I'm building and I got the result you're looking for via `[placemark locality]`

Comment: Hey Your answer looks useful but its not working on my device.I checked here also its giving me the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, glad to help...Hmmm...it's (remotely) possible that your placemark is in a location that has no locality. IOW, an unincorporated location. I live in south Florida USA and I was able to test the code and return the city where my device was physically located (Hallandale Beach, FL) at the time of the test. Can you change locations and test again?